# How do I force Spotify's cache into RAM?

Tags: ram, chroot, cache, spotify

Spotify is writing enormous amounts of data onto my hard drive. As is expected from an app that downloads every song it plays and then deletes it after you close the app. All that reading and writing is wrecking havoc on my computer. I've had four disk checks on my hard drive already.

A few weeks back, I put Spotify's cache location into RAM (/dev/shm/). Now, the settings say the cache is in RAM but on checking, ram is a few kilobytes and the Spotify cache is back to it's usual gigabyte-range of data.

I've also tried creating a symlink between Spotify's cache directory and the RAM directory. That didn't work. Spotify destroyed it as soon as the app started. I'm thinking of writing a script and chrooting Spotify into RAM. I love Spotify but I could get the same service from Youtube without the constant wearing-down of my drives.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "I've had four disk checks on my hard drive already."?

Comment: On startup, my computer asks me to run fsck on the local disk drive.

Comment: I've added a partial answer for your fsck messages.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

**Step #1:**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Step #2:**

- undo the changes that you tried to make to Spotify's cache to /dev/shm. I'm not sure if that's the right place to try and do that. The data file that it's writing is not that large, and if it deletes it on its own, then there's no worries.

Comment: Counter to "there's no worries". SSD users have a very good reason to be worried if Spotify uses excessive writes.

Comment: @KazWolfe is /dev/shm the correct place to move that cache file to RAM?

Comment: I'm not sure about the correct location, or even how to solve it. I'm just saying it can be a concern for SSD users.

Comment: @KazWolfe  OP indicates a hard drive.

Comment: I've followed these steps four times before asking this question. It only happens when I go on a Spotify binge. When I go to the cache folder, it's overflowing with data and /dev/shm was working for a long time. According to what I've read, it goes directly into RAM.

Comment: @KI4JGT as Kaz Wolfe mentions... I don't know how to modify Spotify's cache behaviour either. And at this time, I can't say if the mods that you've made have anything to do with the fsck messages that you've been getting... but it is kind of suspicious. Were you able to successfully run the fsck from my answer?